# First-time XSLT: call-template, with-param, XPath location path

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is an xml file that I wish to parse with XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myXSLTSheet.xsl" ?>
<us:TopLevelTag xmlns:ut='http://www.umbrellacorp.com/oagis/1' xmlns:ot='http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9' >
    <ut:SecondLevelTag>
    <ut:ThirdLevelTag>
    </ut:ThirdLevelTag>
    </ut:SecondLevelTag>
    <ut:SecondLevelTag>
    <ut:ThirdLevelTag>
          <ut:FourthLevelTag>                        
            <ot:FifthLevelTag>
               <ot:SixthLevelTag>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag1>Thing1</ot:SeventhLevelTag>
               </ot:SixthLevelTag>
               <ot:SixthLevelTag>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag1>Thing2</ot:SeventhLevelTag>
               </ot:SixthLevelTag>
               <ot:SixthLevelTag>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag1>Thing3</ot:SeventhLevelTag>
               </ot:SixthLevelTag>
               <ot:SixthLevelTag>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag1>Thing4</ot:SeventhLevelTag>
               </ot:SixthLevelTag>
               <ot:SixthLevelTag>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag1>Thing5</ot:SeventhLevelTag>
               </ot:SixthLevelTag>
            </ot:FifthLevelTag>
            <ot:FifthLevelTag>
               <ot:SixthLevelTag>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing6</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing7</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing8</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing9</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing10</ot:SeventhLevelTag2> 
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing11</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing12</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing13</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
          <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing14</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
          <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing15</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
               </ot:SixthLevelTag>
            </ot:FifthLevelTag>                
         </ut:FourthLevelTag>            
       </ut:ThirdLevelTag>  
    </ut:SecondLevelTag1>
</us:TopLevelTag>
```

Here is the xlst file to do the parsing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version ="1.0"

        xmlns:ut="http://www.umbrellacorp.com/oagis/1" xmlns:ot="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" >

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:call-template name="spec1">
        <xsl:with-param name="match" select="ut:TopLevelTag/ut:SecondLevelTag[1]/ut:ThirdLevelTag[100]/ut:FourthLevelTag[1]/ot:FifthLevelTag[1]" />
    </xsl:call-template>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/" name="spec1">

    <xsl:param name="match" />

    <xsl:for-each select="$match/ot:SixthLevelTag">

        Value: <xsl:value-of select="ot:SeventhLevelTag"/><br/>

    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help, the xslt file doesn't return anything.  I think that the template "match" attributes may be set wrong, or that I am using the "param" variable incorrectly.

Comment: My guess is that you aren't using an XML/XSLT aware IDE as it would pick up on issues like your XML not being valid. I personally use Oxygen XML but that costs money. Netbeans has a free XSLT plug-in that seems to work and may very well be worth a try

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `us:TopLevelTag` is meant to be an `ut:TopLevelTag`.

`ut:TopLevelTag/ut:SecondLevelTag[1]/ut:ThirdLevelTag[100]` matches nothing, since `ut:TopLevelTag/ut:SecondLevelTag[1]` is an element with exactly on `ut:ThirdLevelTag` in it. Therefore, the whole xslt expression matches nothing.

As a general guideline, it is usually neither necessary nor necessarily a good idea to try and encode the complete path at once. I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve in the above (and my guess is that you should try considerably smaller examples for posting questions), but it may be worth doing away with the long match and just checking `<xsl:for-each select='.//ot:SixthLevelTag'>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the **match** attribute from the second template, otherwise it's an error (the template will be automatically called with empty parameter.) Then, if you clean the mess in your sample xml (make closing tags match opening, use valid namespace prefixes etc) it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of problems with this one.  First, your XML is not well formed (see Thing1, et al.), and there is a namespace prefix, "us" that is not declared. I changed a few things to create a valid xml doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myXSLTSheet.xsl" ?>
<ut:TopLevelTag xmlns:ut='http://www.umbrellacorp.com/oagis/1' xmlns:ot='http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9' >
    <ut:SecondLevelTag>
    <ut:ThirdLevelTag>
    </ut:ThirdLevelTag>
    </ut:SecondLevelTag>
    <ut:SecondLevelTag1>
    <ut:ThirdLevelTag>
          <ut:FourthLevelTag>                        
            <ot:FifthLevelTag>
               <ot:SixthLevelTag>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag1>Thing1</ot:SeventhLevelTag1>
               </ot:SixthLevelTag>
               <ot:SixthLevelTag>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag1>Thing2</ot:SeventhLevelTag1>
               </ot:SixthLevelTag>
               <ot:SixthLevelTag>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag1>Thing3</ot:SeventhLevelTag1>
               </ot:SixthLevelTag>
               <ot:SixthLevelTag>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag1>Thing4</ot:SeventhLevelTag1>
               </ot:SixthLevelTag>
               <ot:SixthLevelTag>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag1>Thing5</ot:SeventhLevelTag1>
               </ot:SixthLevelTag>
            </ot:FifthLevelTag>
            <ot:FifthLevelTag>
               <ot:SixthLevelTag>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing6</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing7</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing8</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing9</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing10</ot:SeventhLevelTag2> 
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing11</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing12</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
                  <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing13</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
          <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing14</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
          <ot:SeventhLevelTag2>Thing15</ot:SeventhLevelTag2>
               </ot:SixthLevelTag>
            </ot:FifthLevelTag>                
         </ut:FourthLevelTag>            
       </ut:ThirdLevelTag>  
    </ut:SecondLevelTag1>
</ut:TopLevelTag>
```

I went ahead and simplified the xslt as well:  the call-template is unnecessary for what you are trying to do, which is getting all of the SeventhLevelTags:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version ="1.0"

            xmlns:ut="http://www.umbrellacorp.com/oagis/1" xmlns:ot="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" >

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="//ot:SeventhLevelTag">

            Value: <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Running this in the browser should give you what you are looking for.